# I can't run my spring roo project

Tags: spring-roo

I've been reading Getting started with Spring Roo which I really liked and I've tried to run a very similar project using neo4j too. I'm using STS and tc Server 2.6. The server starts up but the project can't be deployed although I haven't done anything strange or anything which isn't explained in the Getting started.

I've got one error, which is:

```
GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase   

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [C:\Program Files\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\wtpwebapps\vocabulary\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext-graph.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/EmbeddedGraphDatabase
```

Is this the real error? Where should I include this class/library?

I want to use Tomcat /manager webapp to get more details about the deploying but I can't set the password because I can't overwrite tomcat-users.xml. Is there another way to set the password for the user manager-gui?

My last question, my goal is to develop webapps using Spring Roo and GWT. I'm reading Spring MVC Step-by-step although this document is quite old but I'm learning what does every piece of the puzzle. I would like to know your experience, whether Roo+GWT is a good choice, whether I'm reading good documents, which other guides could I read...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue when following. The maven dependency setup for the neo4j embeddedgraph is wrong.

Opene you projects pom.xml file and manually change the dependency (in the  section) to version 1.6 (the current stable release):

```
<neo4j.version>1.6</neo4j.version>
```

After doing this, you might still have a problem starting the vFabric tc server:

```
2012-02-09 22:53:55,797 [Thread-10] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationCheck': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError: transactionManager not correctly configured, please refer to the manual, setup section
```

There is a problem with the setup of the transaction management in the application xml setup files. If there is no need for using such, then the application can be tested using the maven jetty plugin directly from roo, using the perform command:

```
perform command --mavenCommand jetty:run-war
```

Hope this helps